# Oci8Exception in Oci8.php (line 460)

Tags: oracle, laravel

I met a problem when i use laravel 5.4 to connect to oracle, it will throw the error like this, i googled for days, but can't solve the problem, i don't know where i did wrong, i need your help.

```js
(1/1) Oci8Exception
in Oci8.php (line 460)
at Oci8->connect('(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.98)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA =(SID = fanhua)))', 'tianhengrd', 'tianheng123', array(2, 0, 2, 'charset' => 'AL32UTF8'), 'AL32UTF8')
in Oci8.php (line 78)
at Oci8->__construct('(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.98)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA =(SID = fanhua)))', 'tianhengrd', 'tianheng123', array(2, 0, 2, 'charset' => 'AL32UTF8'))
in OracleConnector.php (line 204)
at OracleConnector->createConnection('(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.98)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA =(SID = fanhua)))', array('driver' => 'oracle', 'tns' => '', 'host' => '192.168.2.98', 'port' => '1521', 'database' => 'fanhua', 'username' => 'tianhengrd', 'password' => 'tianheng123', 'charset' => 'AL32UTF8', 'prefix' => '', 'prefix_schema' => '', 'options' => array(2)), array(2, 0, 2, 'charset' => 'AL32UTF8'))
in OracleConnector.php (line 35)
at OracleConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'oracle', 'tns' => '', 'host' => '192.168.2.98', 'port' => '1521', 'database' => 'fanhua', 'username' => 'tianhengrd', 'password' => 'tianheng123', 'charset' => 'AL32UTF8', 'prefix' => '', 'prefix_schema' => '', 'options' => array(2)))
in Oci8ServiceProvider.php (line 48)
at Oci8ServiceProvider->Yajra\Oci8\{closure}(array('driver' => 'oracle', 'tns' => '', 'host' => '192.168.2.98', 'port' => '1521', 'database' => 'fanhua', 'username' => 'tianhengrd', 'password' => 'tianheng123', 'charset' => 'AL32UTF8', 'prefix' => '', 'prefix_schema' => '', 'options' => array(2)), 'fanhua')
at call_user_func(object(Closure), array('driver' => 'oracle', 'tns' => '', 'host' => '192.168.2.98', 'port' => '1521', 'database' => 'fanhua', 'username' => 'tianhengrd', 'password' => 'tianheng123', 'charset' => 'AL32UTF8', 'prefix' => '', 'prefix_schema' => '', 'options' => array(2)), 'fanhua')
in DatabaseManager.php (line 113)
at DatabaseManager->makeConnection('fanhua')
in DatabaseManager.php (line 71)
at DatabaseManager->connection('fanhua')
in Model.php (line 1041)
at Model::resolveConnection(null)
in Model.php (line 1007)
at Model->getConnection()
in Model.php (line 855)
at Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
in Model.php (line 814)
at Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
in Model.php (line 798)
at Model->newQuery()
in OracleUserProvider.php (line 25)
at OracleUserProvider->retrieveByCredentials(array('username' => 'admin', 'password' => '123456'))
in SessionGuard.php (line 352)
at SessionGuard->attempt(array('username' => 'admin', 'password' => '123456'), false)
in AuthenticatesUsers.php (line 76)
at LoginController->attemptLogin(object(Request))
in AuthenticatesUsers.php (line 41)
at LoginController->login(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LoginController), 'login'), array(object(Request)))
in Controller.php (line 55)
at Controller->callAction('login', array(object(Request)))
in ControllerDispatcher.php (line 44)
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(LoginController), 'login')
in Route.php (line 203)
at Route->runController()
in Route.php (line 160)
at Route->run()
in Router.php (line 574)
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php (line 24)
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in SubstituteBindings.php (line 41)
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ShareErrorsFromSession.php (line 49)
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in StartSession.php (line 64)
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php (line 37)
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in EncryptCookies.php (line 59)
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Router.php (line 576)
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))
in Router.php (line 535)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 513)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 176)
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php (line 151)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php (line 53)
```

my env file is like this, and my database.php is below,

```js
ORACLE_DB_TNS=
ORACLE_DB_HOST=192.168.2.98
ORACLE_DB_PORT=1521
ORACLE_DB_DATABASE=fanhua
ORACLE_DB_USERNAME=tianhengrd
ORACLE_DB_PASSWORD=tianheng123
ORACLE_DB_PREFIX=
ORACLE_DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX=


'fanhua' => [
            'driver'        => 'oracle',
            'tns'           => env('ORACLE_DB_TNS', ''),
            'host'          => env('ORACLE_DB_HOST', ''),
            'port'          => env('ORACLE_DB_PORT', '1521'),
            'database'      => env('ORACLE_DB_DATABASE', ''),
            'username'      => env('ORACLE_DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password'      => env('ORACLE_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'       => env('ORACLE_DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
            'prefix'        => env('ORACLE_DB_PREFIX', ''),
            'prefix_schema' => env('ORACLE_DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX', ''),
            'options' => [
                PDO::ATTR_CASE         => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
            ]
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a pure-PHP script calling `oci_connect()` with the DB credentials and connect string shown in your trace output.  Something like:

```
<?php
$c = oci_connect('tianhengrd, 'tianheng123', '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.2.98)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=fanhua)))', 'AL32UTF8')
if (!$c) {
  $m = oci_error(); 
  trigger_error($m['message'], E_USER_ERROR); 
}
```

This will confirm they are valid and show what error is happening if they are not.  Most modern databases connection strings use 'service names' not 'SIDs', so I'd expect to see `'... (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = fanhua)) ...'`

Comment: I tryed your code, it throws error oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and it was apache permission

1. check you Apache variables $ORACLE_HOME AND LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. check permission apache for diretorys oracle_home and ld_library

alway check apache error log